# is it bad to use 301,302 redirects after form submission

Tags: http-status-code-301, http-status-code-302

Is it bad to use 301, 302 redirects after processing a form submission. Or is it only advised to use for pages that have "really been moved". I can show users nice urls if I use redirects.

Please advice.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it is not bad. It's actually recommended best practice and called [PRG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) (POST, Redirect, GET). This prevents users from seeing the nasty "Do you really want to send this form again?" message.

It's recommended that you send *303* (See Other) or *302* (Found). *301* is saying that this resource has been relocated permanently.

Comment: what about using 303 . can i safely use 303?

Comment: @robert Absolutely. It's actually recommended by the specs (according to the Wikipedia article, havent read the actual spec in a while).

Answer (score 0):

`302 Found` sounds valid, if you are redirecting the user to the newly created object.
However, be aware that some network security scanners (as BlueCoat) may wish to block such redirections.

Comment: @robert Yes it will. However, it will never submit any forms.